# learning drupal7 simple module development

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am new to drupal. Have done installation and gone through administration control system.

Now I want to learn custom module development. I have gone through process of building module. But not getting exactly just by reading.

can any one give me a link of sample module(tutorial) for learning?

Comment: Take a look at the views and features module. Features allows you not only to generate a new custom module but also to export content types, views, taxonomie etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check http://drupal.org/project/examples

From the project page:

> This project aims to provide high-quality, well-documented API examples for a broad range of Drupal core functionality.
>   
> Developers can learn how to use a particular API quickly by experimenting with the examples, and adapt them for their own use.

This module has a wide range of examples, 25 submodules with good help tutorials.
Blocks, menus, ajax, email, form, filter and so on.